# Trying to link image src from local stored android gallery in Nativescript

Tags: image-processing, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have an object which stores the file path of a recently saved image to the gallery. The file path that this plugin creates looks like this

```
\/storage\/emulated\/0\/UntitledSl1480672413741\/image-1091296775.jpg
```

If I Have XML

```
<image src="{{thumbnailimage}}"></image>
```

And in component

```
var imageSource = require("image-source");
var fs = require("file-system");
import ImageModule = require("ui/image");

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
     private thumbnailimage : ImageModule.Image;
     ngOnInit(){
        this.thumbnailimage = "\/storage\/emulated\/0\/UntitledSl1480672413741\/image-1091296775.jpg";
        }
    }
```

It gives this error

> Error: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:

Now what? the filepath that is saved looks odd too, I assume its an android format

trying to view this directly in my image tags in my page XML, eg

```
<image src="\/storage\/emulated\/0\/UntitledSl1480672413741\/image-1091296775.jpg"></image>
<image src="file://storage/emulated/0/UntitledSl1480672413741/image-1091296775.jpg"></image>
```

Gives these error

> Error: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /storage/emulated/0/UntitledSl1480672413741/image-1091296775.jpg
>
> Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: libcore.net.url.FtpURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.HttpURLConnection

I'm not sure how the file path is supposed to be properly formatted, I know the documents say use ~ but that is for relative path only.

Comment: Try this `<image src="file:///storage/emulated/0/UntitledSl1480672413741/image-1091296775.jpg"></image>` use three '/' .
or you can just use `<image src = "/storage/emulated/0/UntitledSl1480672413741/image-1091296775.jpg"></image>`

Comment: <image src = "/storage/emulated/0/UntitledSl1480672413741/image-109129677‌​5.jpg"></image>
Second one worked, thanks!

Comment: Which plugin did you mean when saying "...The file path that this plugin create... "

Comment: My own custom plugin, it saves an image from url sent from ns app then posts back the path